# How to graph all the occurences of NA by bins of positions

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, histogram

I am a little new to R, and I am looking to graph all the occurrences of `NA` over the change in position as a histogram. I am starting to use `ggplot` but I'm not sure where to start?

```
df <- data.frame(position=c(3, 5, 6, 7, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 35, 46, 78, 98, 100, 
                            145, 146, 147), 
                 petal15=c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 
                           0, NA), 
                 petal20=c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 
                           0, 0))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "occurrences of NA over the change in position"?

Comment: @jay.sf Sorry I forgot to add the position data, What I'm looking to do is whenever petal15 or petal20 have an occurrence of NA I want to graph that as a histogram with a bin size (to be determined later). Ignoring the 1 and o's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you are looking for this.

```
hist(rowSums(is.na(df)), xlab='occurrences', col=4, main="NA's")
```

[image]

### Edit

To implement your idea in the comment, we first want a list of the positions.

```
(pos <- lapply((0:14)*10 + 1, \(x) (0:9) + x))
# [[1]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#
# [...]
#
# [[15]]
# [1] 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
```

Using `sapply` we create the desired matrix and pipe it to `barplot()`.

```
sapply(pos, \(i) colSums(is.na(df[df$position %in% i, -1]))) |>
  barplot(beside=TRUE, xlim=c(1, 48), ylim=c(0, 2.5), col=3:4,
          xlab='Occurences', ylab='Freq', main="NA's",
          legend.text=names(df[-1]), args.legend=list(x='topright'),
          names.arg=Reduce(\(x, y) paste0(x, '-', y), 
                           as.data.frame(t(sapply(pos, range)))),
          cex.names=.8) 
box()
```

[image]

*Note:*

```
R.version.string
# [1] "R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(position = c(3, 5, 6, 7, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 35, 
46, 78, 98, 100, 145, 146, 147), petal15 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, NA), petal20 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Comment: kinda, Im trying to graph it against the position...so between 0-10 there are 0 occurrences of NA of petal15 or petal 20, but position 11-20 will have 2 occurrences of NA for Petal15 but 0 for petal20 so there would be a bar of freq=2 for petal15 but a bar of freq=0 for petal20. Repeat up until position 141 to 150.

Comment: @James Wow, that's slightly more complicated. See edit please.

Comment: OMG thankyou, I know it was so complicated thankyou for helping me with it!

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution - pivot longer, then filter for all NAs, then plot a histogram as suggested above, but with ggplot instead.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_na <- 
  df %>%
  pivot_longer(-position) %>%
  filter(is.na(value)) 
  
ggplot(df_na, aes(position, fill = name)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,150,10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>